# angular material toolbar cannot center

Tags: angular, angular-material

i'm trying to center an icon in a material toolbar. Unfortunately its moved a bit to the right because i have a seccond image at the lefter side. Here is my code:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
<mat-toolbar-row>
  <span>
    <img class="premiumPartner" src="https://resources.redbull.com/logos/redbullcom/v1/redbullcom-logo.svg">
  </span>
  <span class="span">
    <img class="logo" src="../assets/eatsmarticon.png">
  </span>
 <span class="example-spacer"></span>
 <mat-icon class="example-icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example heart icon">tune</mat-icon>
```

and here is my style:

```
.logo{
 height: 56px;
 width: 56px;
 vertical-align: middle;

 }
.premiumPartner{
height: 30px;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
 }

 .span {
margin: auto;
```

}

Unfortunately it looks like this:

[image: toolbar]

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you wish to center the middle image in the middle of **the screen** itself.

I noticed your left image uses position: relative, therefore it pushes content when it is displayed, changing it to absolute would fix this issue, but your images will start to climb on one another when the screen gets smaller.

```
.premiumPartner {
   height: 30px;
   vertical-align: middle;

   /* changed values */
   position: absolute;
}
```

You will need to do something similar to the icon on the right as well, if you wish to center it perfectly.

Or you can just take the middle image itself and give it position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you should use FlexLayout: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout

Here is an example how it works:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="space-between center>
    <img class="premiumPartner" src="https://resources.redbull.com/logos/redbullcom/v1/redbullcom-logo.svg">
    <img class="logo" src="../assets/eatsmarticon.png">
    <mat-icon class="example-icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example heart icon">tune</mat-icon>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

The fxLayout will add the Flex Layout to your dom (direction default row). The fxLayoutAlign will specify the alignment of the direction. For row is the order horizontal vertical (space-between center).

Answer (score 0):

I always use standard `<table>` html for stuff like this. always works, zero time spent coding.